# Is there any possible query where i can get which kitchen stock out how much time in that give created_at time range

Tags: mysql

I have a table having kitchen stock log STOCK_OUT and STOCK_IN.

is there any possible query where i can get which kitchen stock out how much time in that give created_at time range.

[image]

Comment: Please put some efforts in framing a question with **relevant and minimal sample data** showcasing your requirements, and **corresponding expected output**. Please read this link: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952/2469308)

Comment: very similar questions asking to calculate differences between rows get asked regularly. What research did you do? What attempt did you make to solve the problem? We're not a free write-my-code service, and we dislike repeating ourselves. We're happy to _help_ you, but we don't just go and do the whole thing for you. If you can show us your attempt and explain any actual problem you're facing then please edit your question and you will get a much better response. "I haven't even thought about this yet" is not a valid question / problem.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understand your question correctly, but I think this is what you are looking for:

```
 SELECT * from TABLE where operation='STOCK_OUT' and created_at between "2018-
 11-25 14:11:12" and "2018-11-28 12:35:13"
```

This will give the rows in the TABLE that were 'STOCK_OUT' during the created_at range specified in the query